# maven assembly, fail if file not found

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

Building a [maven assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html), I left with something like this:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>

        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>

        <includes>

            <include>LICENSE.md</include>
            ...
```

> How can I enforce the existence of `LICENSE.md`?

In the given example, no warning is thrown if this file is not present, ideally, I would like to fail the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to fail the build according to different constraints, you should look into the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html). This plugin allows the configuration of rules that are checked, and if any of them is not passing, it makes the build fail.

There is a built-in rule to check for the existence of a file, called [`requireFilesExist`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html):

> This rule checks that the specified list of files exist.

As such, in order to fail the build if the file `LICENSE.md` is not present, you could have:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-license</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireFilesExist>
            <files>
              <file>${project.basedir}/LICENSE.md</file>
            </files>
          </requireFilesExist>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This runs by default in the `validate` phase, [which is the first phase invoked](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) in the build, so that the build will fail fast if the file isn't present.

Comment: Huzzah! Exactly the behavior I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have use other means to ensure that file is present (maven-ant plugin, [maven enforcer](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html)). Strict filtering is not available for fileset. It is only available for dependencyset. See [this](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Created-MASSEMBLY-488-useStrictFiltering-in-a-fileSet-in-the-assembly-descriptor-doesn-t-work-td509795.html) relevant mail chain.